# drag UITableView

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uiview, drag, gesture

I have a little problem, I try to drag a UITableview, whit this code I drag a view but I can't drag a uitableivew, where is the problem?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.table addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];

}
```

I work on an iPad application

Comment: I believe you will have the same issue with any `UIScrollView` subclass (and `UITableView` is one oh these classes), as it handles the touches by itself. The way the framework is implemented, it would not know if you are trying to scroll the table or drag it

Comment: you're right, I solved in another way, I add a minimumNumberOfTouches so if an user want to move the table can move it with 2 finger, while qhit one finger he can scroll the table!

Answer (score 0):

Does your table bounce or scroll? Then it means your table's scroll takes the touch and you won't get it. Observe your table's scroll delegate and implement the same code there. It will work.